# Slack API - Get my lastest message to a user

Tags: bots, message, slack, slack-api, userinfo

How can I get my lastest message to a User?
I have a bot, so I wanna know when is lastest time I contact (direct message, mention...) to it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `conversations.history` method. This returns the whole history of a channel or Direct message. You can then iterate over this and fetch the most recent message.